# Google Analytics, track page unload event

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, dom-events, synchronous

I'm trying to accomplish tracking an event when a user leaves the page with Google Analytics (analytics.js). Though it is unknown how the user will leave, it may be because of an external link or just closing the tab. So my thought was to hook onto the beforeunload or unload event and then:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'some', 'other', 'data');
});
```

Now my question is, will the request to the GA server be synchronous or can I somehow force that behaviour with the [hitCallback](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/advanced#hitCallback) property? If that is not possible, how else can I achieve this? Preferably without having to set a timeout or fixed waiting time for the user!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The request will not be synchronous, GA tracking calls never are.

The only way to ensure the call completes is to make sure the page stays open long enough - for an event on a link you would normally do this with a timeout potentially combined with a hitCallback, as you mentioned.

The only way to keep a window open when the user closes a tab is to return a value from your beforeunload handler, which will prompt a "Confirm Navigation" alert. That would be a really bad solution just to track a GA event, obviously.

Answer (score 11):

There is a way to make sure the request will be sent to GA. Simo Ahava wrote a very good blog post titled - 
"[Leverage useBeacon And beforeunload In Google Analytics](http://www.simoahava.com/analytics/leverage-usebeacon-beforeunload-google-analytics/)".

Utilizing the brilliant [sendBeacon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/navigator.sendBeacon) solution. Here's quote which addresses the selected answer of this question:

> User agents will typically ignore asynchronous XMLHttpRequests made in
>   an unload handler. To solve this problem, analytics and diagnostics
>   code will typically make a synchronous XMLHttpRequest in an unload or
>   beforeunload handler to submit the data. The synchronous
>   XMLHttpRequest forces the User Agent to delay unloading the document,
>   and makes the next navigation appear to be slower. There is nothing
>   the next page can do to avoid this perception of poor page load
>   performance.
>
> There are other techniques used to ensure that data is submitted. One
>   such technique is to delay the unload in order to submit data by
>   creating an Image element and setting its src attribute within the
>   unload handler. As most user agents will delay the unload to complete
>   the pending image load, data can be submitted during the unload.
>   Another technique is to create a no-op loop for several seconds within
>   the unload handler to delay the unload and submit data to a server.
>
> Not only do these techniques represent poor coding patterns, some of
>   them are unreliable and also result in the perception of poor page
>   load performance for the next navigation.

Comment: Good indeed, only issue with `sendBeacon` is browser support (eg not supported by IE<11 or Safari<11.4). Overall support seems to be around 85%: https://caniuse.com/#feat=beacon

Comment: @Max - That is correct, **but** It's not an issue since this is better than nothing. There's no alternative. Also, I personally choose to work on projects that don't require IE use, and many projects nowadays don't have IE support under their requirements, for example B2B dashboards and so on.

Answer (score 3):

Set [`transport` to `beacon`, with `ga`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#transport):

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
    ga('send', 'event', 'page_unload', 'bye bye', {transport: 'beacon'});
});
```

Or [`transport_type` to `beacon`, with `gtag`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#specify_different_transport_mechanisms):

```js
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function() {
  gtag('event', 'page_unload', {
    'event_category': 'my cat',
    'event_label': 'my label',
    'transport_type': 'beacon'  // <--- important part here
  });
});
```

For what is worth, beacon should become the default transport mode anyway. As of [2020-09](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/sending-data#specify_different_transport_mechanisms):

> Currently, gtag.js only uses navigator.sendBeacon if the transport
> mechanism is set to 'beacon'. However, in the future, gtag.js will
> likely switch to using 'beacon' as the default mechanism in browsers
> that support it.

Answer (score 0):

***As pointed out by tomconnors, this does NOT work. I'm leaving the answer to help warn anyone thinking about doing it this way. Beacon transport is probably the way to go, but wasn't widely supported at the time of the original answer.***

You can wait for a hit to be sent to Google Analytics in the page `onunload`, but it does require a busy loop. In my case this did not delay user navigation, as the page was a popup window that is dedicated to a webapp. I'd be more concerned about doing this inline with normal web page navigation. Still, I had to take 2 showers to get the filth off after committing code with a busy loop.

```
var MAX_WAIT_MS = 1000;
var _waitForFinalHit = false;

function recordFinalHit() {
    _waitForFinalHit = true;

    ga('send', 'event', 'some', 'other', 'data', {
        'hitCallback': function() {
            _waitForFinalHit = false;
        }
    });
}

function waitForFinalHit() {
    var waitStart = new Date().getTime();
    while (_waitForFinalHit
        && (new Date().getTime() - waitStart < MAX_WAIT_MS)) { }
}

function myOnUnload() {
    recordFinalHit();
    // Do your other final stuff here...
    waitForFinalHit();
}

window.onunload = myOnUnload;
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, this will always busy loop for MAX_WAIT_MS, because the loop never cedes control back to the browser, so the request callback can never execute, and _waitForFinalHit can never be updated. I am not aware of any workaround.